# Im having issues getting data out of a json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the lat, long values out of a response the response is coming from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ch3%209dq&sensor=false

i have created a fiddle to show where i am up to: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesRand/H4ZzQ/2/

i think this might be due to it being a multi level response.

the values i need are:

```
"location" : {
               "lat" : 53.07399710,
               "lng" : -2.80763780
},
```

im not 100% sure about json and how to get data out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.results[0].geometry.location.lat
data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
```

Additionally, to debug, use any modern browser, and `console.log(data)`, then you can walk through the object properties in JavaScript console

Your example working:

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesRand/H4ZzQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in your fiddle, seems to work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=cw69ee&sensor=false', function(data) {
             $('#stage').html('<p> location: ' +
                              data.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ' , ' +
                              data.results[0].geometry.location.lng + '</p>');
          });
      });
   });
```